# How to persist Select2 createSearchChoice choice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

My code is as below, which works awesome.

But there is one bug in it, When a new tag is created it's great, but after a button is pressed on the form I clear out all the inputs including the select2.

What I would expect to happen is, because I did a `createSearchChoice` the previously created search choice should show up in the dropdown.

Instead it simple vanishes., So How can I make the new choice persistent?

```
clipper.folderSelect.select2({
        placeholder: 'Select Folders...',
        data: clipper.folderSelect.data('folders'),
        closeOnSelect: false,
        multiple: true,
        createSearchChoice:function(term, data) {
            term = $.trim(term.toLowerCase());
            var Dterm = term.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + term.substr(1);
            if ($(data).filter(function() {
                return (this.text.localeCompare(Dterm) === 0);
            }).length === 0) {
                return {id:term, text: Dterm, isNew: true};
            }
        },
        formatResult: function(term) {
            if (term.isNew) {
                return term.text + '<span class="label label-warning pull-right">New</span>';
            }
            else {
                return term.text;
            }
        }
    });
```